# TIBCO Hawk Sample ConsoleApp Testing

Tags: tibco

I tried to test Hawk sample program ConsoleApp, I executed the shell list below on aix platform,

[image]

I have added `\hawk\lib\util.jar`  into project  external jar, but error message keep showing.
anyone could give advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks it is trivial issue with `classpath`. Can you add below path to existing `classpath` and try?

`$CLASSPATH:$TIBCO_HOME/designer/<version>/hawk/<version>/lib:`

Note to replace the variables in the above.